# intel real sense programming about librealsense2

Tags: c++, realsense

I want to get `1280x720` depth image and `1280x720` color image.

So I founded as `coded` :

```
// License: Apache 2.0. See LICENSE file in root directory.
// Copyright(c) 2017 Intel Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

#include "librealsense2/rs.hpp" // Include RealSense Cross Platform API
#include "example.hpp"          // Include short list of convenience functions for rendering
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "stb-master\stb_image_write.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


// Capture Example demonstrates how to
// capture depth and color video streams and render them to the screen



int main(int argc, char * argv[]) try
{
    int width = 1280;
    int height = 720;
    rs2::log_to_console(RS2_LOG_SEVERITY_ERROR);
    // Create a simple OpenGL window for rendering:
    window app(width, height, "RealSense Capture Example");
    // Declare two textures on the GPU, one for color and one for depth
    texture depth_image, color_image;

    // Declare depth colorizer for pretty visualization of depth data
    rs2::colorizer color_map;
    color_map.set_option(RS2_OPTION_HISTOGRAM_EQUALIZATION_ENABLED,1.f);
    color_map.set_option(RS2_OPTION_COLOR_SCHEME, 2.f);

    // Declare RealSense pipeline, encapsulating the actual device and sensors
    rs2::pipeline pipe;
    // Start streaming with default recommended configuration

    pipe.start();

    while (app) // Application still alive?
    {
        rs2::frameset data = pipe.wait_for_frames(); // Wait for next set of frames from the camera

        rs2::frame depth = color_map(data.get_depth_frame()); // Find and colorize the depth data
        rs2::frame color = data.get_color_frame();            // Find the color data

                                                              // For cameras that don't have RGB sensor, we'll render infrared frames instead of color
        if (!color)
            color = data.get_infrared_frame();

        // Render depth on to the first half of the screen and color on to the second
        depth_image.render(depth, { 0,               0, app.width() / 2, app.height() });
        color_image.render(color, { app.width() / 2, 0, app.width() / 2, app.height() });
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
catch (const rs2::error & e)
{
    std::cerr << "RealSense error calling " << e.get_failed_function() << "(" << e.get_failed_args() << "):\n    " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

I want to this..

1. Push the <kbd>c</kbd> <- keyboard value
2. save the color image and depth image in PNG foramt

I can get the `code` about `2`.
but, i don't know how to call the action when I press the "c"

I guess I have to use this `example.hpp`.

```
GLFWwindow * win = glfwCreateWindow(tile_w*cols, tile_h*rows, ss.str().c_str(), 0, 0);
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(win, &dev);

glfwSetKeyCallback(win, [](GLFWwindow * win, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    auto dev = reinterpret_cast<rs::device *>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(win));
    if (action != GLFW_RELEASE) switch (key)
    {
    case GLFW_KEY_R: color_rectification_enabled = !color_rectification_enabled; break;
    case GLFW_KEY_C: align_color_to_depth = !align_color_to_depth; break;
    case GLFW_KEY_D: align_depth_to_color = !align_depth_to_color; break;
    case GLFW_KEY_E:            
        if (dev->supports_option(rs::option::r200_emitter_enabled))
    {
        int value = !dev->get_option(rs::option::r200_emitter_enabled);
        std::cout << "Setting emitter to " << value << std::endl;
        dev->set_option(rs::option::r200_emitter_enabled, value);
    }
                                break;
    case GLFW_KEY_A:
        if (dev->supports_option(rs::option::r200_lr_auto_exposure_enabled))
        {
            int value = !dev->get_option(rs::option::r200_lr_auto_exposure_enabled);
            std::cout << "Setting auto exposure to " << value << std::endl;
            dev->set_option(rs::option::r200_lr_auto_exposure_enabled, value);
        }
        break;
    }

});
```

This code is used in librealsense 1.X version. I would like to change this to librealsense 2.0 version code. But I do not know what to do.

How way do I change this code??

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

Useful samples to get you on your way with RealSense SDK 2.0 and OpenCV are available in the repo at `/wrappers/opencv`

Keep in mind that the Supported Devices by SDK 2.0 are:

```
Intel® RealSense™ Camera D400-Series
Intel® RealSense™ Developer Kit SR300
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to include links to external resources in order to provide context. But answer posts that require a reader to consult an external resource in order to be helpful at all are not considered legit answers according to Stack Overflow's policy. Could you please add the crucial information directly into your post? You may want to consult [answer].